# Add focus to first input on load and next input after success using vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am creating a fill in the blank using vue. I have three components, a parent component where I build the question, an input component where I validate and the text component. I have stripped out a lot of the code to try and keep the question relevant, anything commented out is unsuccessful. Hope I am not out in left field on this one but have never attempted this so thought I would try here.

**First issue:**
Some of the questions have two inputs and I want to auto provide focus to the first input, (using a custom directive ) I am able to gain focus on the last created input. I am not really sure how to access first child I guess. Works well with single input questions though. I have tried doing so by using $refs and $nextTick(()) but no luck.

**Second issue:**
Once one input gets isCorrect I want to auto focus to the next available non correct element. I figured I would have be able to access the child input from the parent component and have been trying [using this link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) but I have been unsuccessful.

Any help or insights is much appreciated. thanks

What it looks like for visual

[image]

What I am after

[image]

**Parent Component**

```
import ivInput from "../inline-components/iv-input.vue";
import ivText from "../inline-components/iv-text.vue";

<component 
    :is="buildQuestion(index)"
    ref="ivWrap"
    v-for="(item, index) in questionParts"
    :key="index">
</component>

export default() {
    components:{
        ivInput,
        ivText
    },
    mounted(){
        // console.log(this.$refs.ivWrap)
        // console.log(this.$refs.iv)
    },
    methods: {
         buildQuestion: function (index) {
            if(this.questionParts[index].includes('*_*')){
                return ivInput
            }else{
                return ivText
           }
         },
         //focus: function (){
            // this.$refs.iv.focus()
            // console.log(this.$refs.iv)
        // }
    }
}
```

**Input Component**

```
<div :class="'iv-input-wrap'">
  <input
    ref="iv"
    v-focus
    type="text"
    v-model="userInput"
    :class="[{'is-correct':isCorrect, 'is-error':isError}, 'iv-input']"
    :disabled="isCorrect">
</div>

export default{
   // directives:{
    // directive definition
      // inserted: function (el) {
      //   el.focus()
      // },
    }
    computed{
        isCorrect: function () {
          if(this.isType == true && this.isMatch == true){
          //  this.$refs.iv.focus()
          //  this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.iv.focus)
           return true
         }
       }
    }
}
```